# TensorFlow 2-tf.keras: How to train a tf.keras multi-task network like MTCNN using tf.data API & TFRecords

Tags: keras, multitasking, tfrecord, tensorflow2.x

Recently I am trying to use TFRecords for training tf.keras model. Since for TensorFlow 2, the most efficient way is to use tf.data API, I try to use it for training my MTCNN Keras model. But here is what confuses me:

According to the original paper, different samples (pos, neg, part-face, landmark) participate in different parts of the training. And each kind of samples have a specific ratio in each mini-batch, i.e., for one mini-batch, the ratios for pos, neg, part-face and landmark samples should be 1:3:1:2.

Thus for example, after I made the four TFRecords of samples, I will need to take 128 samples from the pos tfrecords, 384 from the neg, 128 from the part-face and 256 from the landmark tfrecords and mix them into one mini-batch. And then I need to shuffle the batch before training.

I really do not know how to proceed this when using TFRecords and tf.data API. Now I can only implement all those steps by reading the images & labels batch by batch but it is too slow for training. So I wonder if there is any efficient way to do this.

Any advice is appreciated.

Updated 2020.04.04 15:38
Thanks to @AAudibert, I think his/her answer works very well and I also figured out one way to implement this. Here is the code for reference:

```
raw_pos_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(POS_TFRECORDS_PATH_LIST)
raw_neg_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(NEG_TFRECORDS_PATH_LIST)
raw_part_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(PART_TFRECORDS_PATH_LIST)
raw_landmark_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(LANDMARK_TFRECORDS_PATH_LIST)

image_feature_description = {
    'height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'depth': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'info': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([17], tf.float32),
    'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    }

def _read_tfrecord(serialized_example):

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, image_feature_description)

    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(example['image_raw'], channels = 3) # RGB rather than BGR!!! 
    img = (tf.cast(img, tf.float32) - 127.5) / 128.
    img_shape = [example['height'], example['width'], example['depth']]
    img = tf.reshape(img, img_shape)

    info = example['info']

    return img, info

parsed_pos_dataset = raw_pos_dataset.map(_read_tfrecord)
parsed_neg_dataset = raw_neg_dataset.map(_read_tfrecord)
parsed_part_dataset = raw_part_dataset.map(_read_tfrecord)
parsed_landmark_dataset = raw_landmark_dataset.map(_read_tfrecord)

parsed_image_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((parsed_pos_dataset.repeat().shuffle(16384).batch(int(BATCH_SIZE * DATA_COMPOSE_RATIO[0])), 
                                            parsed_neg_dataset.repeat().shuffle(16384).batch(int(BATCH_SIZE * DATA_COMPOSE_RATIO[1])), 
                                            parsed_part_dataset.repeat().shuffle(16384).batch(int(BATCH_SIZE * DATA_COMPOSE_RATIO[2])), 
                                            parsed_landmark_dataset.repeat().shuffle(16384).batch(int(BATCH_SIZE * DATA_COMPOSE_RATIO[3]))))

def concatenate(pos_info, neg_info, part_info, landmark_info):

    img_tensor = tf.zeros((0, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), dtype = tf.float32)
    label_tensor = tf.zeros((0, 17), dtype = tf.float32)
    pos_img = pos_info[0]
    neg_img = neg_info[0]
    part_img = part_info[0]
    landmark_img = landmark_info[0]
    pos_info = pos_info[1]
    neg_info = neg_info[1]
    part_info = part_info[1]
    landmark_info = landmark_info[1]
    img_tensor = tf.concat([img_tensor, pos_img, neg_img, part_img, landmark_img], axis = 0)
    info_tensor = tf.concat([label_tensor, pos_info, neg_info, part_info, landmark_info], axis = 0)

    return img_tensor, info_tensor

ds = parsed_image_dataset.map(concatenate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sample according to specified ratios using [sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets)

See [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1W4hX_NI4F-u1VnLHLsjWAC48azu9BV25) for an example. I've also copied the code below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 8

pos = tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 100)
neg = tf.data.Dataset.range(100, 200)
part_face = tf.data.Dataset.range(200, 300)
landmark = tf.data.Dataset.range(300, 400)

dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(
    [pos, neg, part_face, landmark], [1/7, 3/7, 1/7, 2/7])
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Optionally shuffle data further. Samples will already be interspersed between datasets.
# dataset = dataset.map(lambda batch: tf.random.shuffle(batch))

for elem in dataset:
  print(elem.numpy())

# Prints
[200 300 100 201 301 302 101 303]
[  0 304 202 102 203 103 305 104]
[306 307 105 204 308 205 206   1]
[207 309 106 107 310 108 311 312]
[208 209 210   2 109 211 110 212]
...
```

Comment: Hi @AAudibert, 
Thanks very much for your solution and I think it works for me. I also implemented one by using tf.concat like:
`
img_tensor = tf.concat([img_tensor, pos_img, neg_img, part_img, landmark_img], axis = 0) 
`
But both ways seem to have one problem that when the number of samples from each of the datasets (pos, neg, part and landmark) are not as the ratio we need (say I have 32 pos, 96 neg, 32 part and 1024 landmark samples), the merged datasets goes wrong even I use .repeat() for each dataset before they are sampled by .sample_from_datasets.

Comment: [MTCNN-Keras](https://github.com/TMaysGGS/MTCNN-Keras/tree/master/Training)This is the custom loss I wrote myself for MTCNN in my repo. When the training goes further, the loss suddenly become 'nan' as well as the validation loss and they never goes back. I wonder if you met some similar cases before. Any advice helps. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @AAudibert, somehow I ran the codes on a Windows CPU tf 2.0.0 PC today and all things going well without the 'nan' loss happening. I might need to verify this result after work.

Comment: @TMaysGGS If you repeat() the input datasets, the ratio is expected to stay the same (though it could be slightly off due to random sampling). If you share code to reproduce the issue, I will try to identify the problem.

Comment: Hi @AAudibert, thanks for your reply. Please see the page [tf bug issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38416) or [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61116002/tensorflow2-tf-keras-loss-and-model-weights-suddenly-become-nan-when-training) that I raised. I checked the training procedure step by step and found that it is the back prop that updates the weights to 'nan', not related to the tf.data.Dataset API. Still if you can look into the page when available, I would appreciate that.